# How to get some examples for each unique value of a field in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a model called NewsArticles which has a field country as a CharField with choices as the country names.

I want to make a queryset getting 4 articles for each country. For now the only way I could think of is to get the unique country list and then get individual querysets for each which seems like a little computational heavy. Like so:

```py
countries = NewsArticle.objects.order_by('country').values_list('country', flat=True).distinct()
final_queryset = NewsArticle.objects.filter(country=countries[0])[:4] 
for index in range(1, len(countries)):
    final_queryset |= NewsArticle.objects.filter(country=countries[index])[:4]
```

Is there a better or more straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

i think you should make another model for **country** and them as foreign key in **NewsArticle** so whenever you create **NewsArticle**. you just need to add country reference on article and it helpful to display all country as drop down while creating articles.
so when you need to fetch record u just need to do follwoing

```
country = country.objects.filter(name="countryname") #it may be  from POST OR GET method
# it just for 1 country. if you want for all country you just need to fetch by all()
if country.exists():
     news_articles = NewsArticle.objects.filter(country_ref=country.get()).order_by("create_date")[:4] #country_ref is foreign key ref
     # it will fetch only 4 record by create date for specified country if you want for more country you need to add loop kind of stuff.
```

Comment: It makes sense but I already have a lot of articles there. Do not want to lose data

Comment: Also, the thing that I said that I want some for each country, I would still have to loop for the countries which is what I do not want to do. As you can see by looping I can do by above method too and in case I need to get according to a query param, I can easily do so using current implementation as well.

Comment: As you point it's right. But saving ref instead of whole string, it's good Idea and it also refused memory size. But btw what you want? Unique article for website ? Or for each user?